# ElasticSearch and Nutch integration

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch, bigdata

I have a question about ElasticSearch and Apache Nutch integration.

I've tried to follow the Nutch+ES guides listed here

https://gist.github.com/xrstf/b48a970098a8e76943b9

https://qbox.io/blog/scraping-the-web-with-nutch-for-elasticsearch

and

http://www.aossama.com/search-engine-with-apache-nutch-mongodb-and-elasticsearch/

Specifically, I was able to set up HDFS+HBase+Nutch and crawl a list of pages (I can confirm that the data is indeed crawled and stored in HBase's webpage table).

I can also get ElasticSearch and Kibana to work with no problem (successfully created a new index and insert some records, confirmed working with Kibana)

However, I couldn't get their **combination** to work. Basically, I after I did the following command on Nutch:

```
nutch inject <file_containing_url>
nutch generate -topN 1
nutch fetch -all
nutch parse -all
nutch updatedb -all
```

Now, I want to index the fetched data into ES, and I followed the guide:

```
nutch index elasticsearch -all
```

However, after this command has finished execution, nothing is changed in ElasticSearch.  The log under runtime/local/logs shows:

```
elastic.ElasticIndexWriter - Processing remaining requests [docs = 0, length = 0, total docs = 0]
```

Which makes me believe ES is not asked to index anything at all by nutch.

Where did I do wrong in the entire process? Do I have to specify something about ES to nutch?

FYI: here are some OS/tools details:
CentOS 6.7, HBase 1.1.3 ElasticSearch 1.7.5, Nutch 2.3.1.
I have modified nutch-site.xml to include ES's properties:

```
    <property>
        <name>plugin.includes</name>
        <!-- do **NOT** enable the parse-html plugin, if you want proper HTML parsing. Use something like parse-tika! -->
        <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|tika|js)|index-(basic|anchor|more)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|indexer-elastic</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>elastic.host</name>
        <value>10.5.140.112</value> <!-- where is ElasticSearch listening -->
    </property>
      <property>
        <name>elastic.cluster</name>
        <value>nutch</value>
      </property>

      <property>
        <name>elastic.index</name>
        <value>nutch</value>
      </property>

      <property>
        <name>elastic.port</name>
        <value>9300</value>
      </property>
```

Thank you all so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I figured this out completely and am not sure if any of the following steps helped, but eventually I successfully indexed some pages to ES:

Here's what I did:

I found out that the ES client java embedded in root_nutch_folder/src/plugins/ is version 1.4.1.  I upgraded that to 1.7.5 (matching my ES local server version), following the howto_upgrade_es.txt file specified in indexer-elastic folder.  However, I don't think this helped the problem because it was nutch who didn't tell ES to index anything, rather than ES Client-Server communication problem.

The key thing I found out that may be affecting the indexing is that my page is actually not crawled, despite records in 'webpage' table in HBase. Initially I tried http://www.espn.com and did nutch inject.  However, since www.espn.com will redirect to espn.go.com, nutch will not automatically follow the redirection and therefore did not download the content HTML.  However, the nutch log will show 'success' all the time.  Even the HBase will record information about www.espn.com.

I reinjected 'http://espn.go.com/' and reran the whole process, and it is now correctly indexed into ES.

I Googled online and found out that I need to setup http.redirect.max in nutch-site.xml, however, no matter how I set it, nutch still won't follow the 302 redirect requests. I guess I will have to live with this.

Answer (score 0):

try `bin/nutch index -all` from the local folder located in runtime folder of nutch folder. Also, if it still deosn't work, try to generate it again with `bin/nutch generate -topN <any_number>`, then fetch and parse them again by using the commands
`bin/nutch fetch -all`
`bin/nutch parse -all`
and lastly, 
`bin/nutch updatedb -all`
then try again with the command in your local folder
`bin/nutch index -all`

Hope it will help.